# When does the underfitted regression model have more precise coefficient estimates?

Tags: regression, variance, matrix, mse, bias-variance-tradeoff

Say we have a full regression model
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{y} &= \mathbf{X} \boldsymbol{\beta} + \boldsymbol{\epsilon}\\
&= \mathbf{X}_p \boldsymbol{\beta}_p + \mathbf{X}_r \boldsymbol{\beta}_r + \boldsymbol{\epsilon}\\
\end{align*}
and a smaller model 
$$
\mathbf{y} = \mathbf{X}_p \boldsymbol{\beta}_p + \widetilde{\boldsymbol{\epsilon}},
$$
where both $\boldsymbol{\epsilon}$ and $\widetilde{\boldsymbol{\epsilon}}$ have the covariance matrix $\sigma^2 \mathbf{I}$. Note that, if the full model is true, $\widetilde{\boldsymbol{\epsilon}} = \mathbf{X}_r \boldsymbol{\beta}_r + \boldsymbol{\epsilon}$

The estimate of $\boldsymbol{\beta}_p$ from the full model is 
$$
\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}_p^* = \left[(\mathbf{X}^\intercal\mathbf{X})^{-1} \mathbf{X}^\intercal \mathbf{y}\right]_p
$$
and the estimate from the smaller model is
$$
\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}_p = (\mathbf{X}_p^\intercal\mathbf{X}_p)^{-1} \mathbf{X}_p^\intercal \mathbf{y}.
$$

The bias for the full model is $\mathbf{0}$, and the bias for the small model is
$$
(\mathbf{X}_p^\intercal \mathbf{X}_p)^{-1} \mathbf{X}_p^\intercal \mathbf{X}_r \boldsymbol{\beta}_r = \mathbf{A}\boldsymbol{\beta}_r .
$$

The covariance matrix for the full model's estimates is
$$
V[\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}^*_p] = 
\sigma^2
\left[(\mathbf{X}^\intercal\mathbf{X})^{-1}\right]_p
$$
and the covariance matrix for the smaller model's estimates is
$$
V[\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}_p] =
\sigma^2
(\mathbf{X}_p^\intercal\mathbf{X}_p)^{-1}.
$$
Note that the difference between these is positive semi-definite by the [formula for inverses of block matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix#Block_matrix_inversion).

What are **all of** the situations where $\text{MSE}[\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}^*_p] - \text{MSE}[\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}_p]$ is positive semi-definite?

- One is when $\mathbf{X}_p^\intercal \mathbf{X}_r = 0$. Then both biases are zero, and 
  $$
  V[\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}^*_p] - V[\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}_p]
  $$
  is positive semidefinite because, as [Yves](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/10479/yves) points out, the variances are the same because the estimates are the same.

Are there any others? [This book](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Introduction+to+Linear+Regression+Analysis%2C+5th+Edition-p-9780470542811) mentions that it is also true when 
$$
V[\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}^*_r] - \boldsymbol{\beta}_r\boldsymbol{\beta}_r^\intercal
$$
is positive semi-definite, but I haven't been able to show this.

Comment: Missing link for the book? When $\mathbf{X}_p^\top \mathbf{X}_r= \mathbf{0}$ I believe that the two estimates are identical (the matrix $\mathbf{X}^\top\mathbf{X}$ is then block diagonal) so they have the same covariance.

Comment: There is a critical ambiguity in this otherwise well-formulated question: the "$\epsilon$" in the full model is not the same as the "$\epsilon$" in the smaller model.  Thus, towards the end, *exactly what do the symbols "$\sigma$" refer to??*  (Do they even represent the same quantity?) Your answer to that will clarify what assumptions you are making as well as clarify the question itself.

Comment: @Yves yes that’s true. I will post a link shortly; thanks.

Comment: @whuber you're correct. I just edited the post.

Comment: Thank you.  However, these models are incompatible: it's not credible that both $\epsilon$ and $\tilde \epsilon$ would have the same variance $\sigma^2.$

Comment: @whuber I don't see why--the variances are conditioning on the covariate data.

Comment: Consider an extreme case where the $\mathbf{X}_r$ suffice for a perfect fit, so that the variance of the $\tilde\epsilon$ is essentially zero.  Indeed, the reduction in error variance is the key component of a standard measure of what is accomplished by including the extra variables (namely, the $F$ statistic). That ought to convince you of the merits of distinguishing the two variances!

Comment: @whuber how would the error variance depend on the covariates? Are you thinking of residuals instead?

Comment: That's not it.  The difference between the models is clear by subtracting one from the other: $\tilde\epsilon = X_r\beta_r+\epsilon.$  Unless $X_r\beta_r$ is identically zero, this will cause the variance of $\tilde\epsilon$ to exceed that of $\epsilon.$

Comment: @whuber or unless you’re assuming $X_r$ and $\beta_r$ are constant, which is what I’m doing here. This is a fairly common assumption, and if it doesn’t hold, then I would replace expectations and variances with their conditional versions.

Comment: I am assuming they are constant and not random.  The problem is that they do vary and that variation must be accommodated by your fitting procedure.  If you insist that the two variances are equal, you are not making a valid comparison of models and you can expect to get an incorrect answer.

Comment: @whuber I wouldn't say I am insisting the two variances are in reality equal--it is logically incoherent to believe two different models are both true. Rather I am showing that, proceeding under the false assumption of the smaller model, the coefficient estimates will have smaller MSE, where the MSE is taken with respect to the true/full model. All of the means and variances above, even though the notation doesn't accurately reflect it, are taken with respect to the first/full/true model.

Comment: That helps me understand a little better what you're doing.  But may I ask why comparing the MSE is relevant while ignoring the potentially enormous bias created by omitting the last $r$ variables?

Comment: @whuber I am not ignoring the bias because the MSE “contains” the bias. It involves the “alias matrix” I mentioned: $\mathbf{A}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sufficient condition mentioned in the book turns out to be necessary as well! I finally verified it using the two different formulas for the inverse of a block matrix.

Looking at the full model estimator
$$
\mathbf{X}^\intercal\mathbf{X} =
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{X}_p^\intercal\mathbf{X}_p &\mathbf{X}_p^\intercal\mathbf{X}_r \\
\mathbf{X}_r^\intercal\mathbf{X}_p & \mathbf{X}_r^\intercal\mathbf{X}_r
\end{bmatrix}
$$
so $\text{MSE}[\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}^*_p]=\sigma^2[(\mathbf{X}^\intercal\mathbf{X})^{-1}]_p$ equals
$$
\sigma^2\left\{(\mathbf{X}_p^\intercal\mathbf{X}_p)^{-1} + (\mathbf{X}_p^\intercal\mathbf{X}_p)^{-1}\mathbf{X}^\intercal_p\mathbf{X}_r(\mathbf{X}_r^\intercal\mathbf{X}_r - \mathbf{X}_r^\intercal \mathbf{X}_p (\mathbf{X}_p^\intercal\mathbf{X}_p)^{-1} \mathbf{X}_p^\intercal \mathbf{X}_r)^{-1}\mathbf{X}_r^\intercal\mathbf{X}_p(\mathbf{X}_p^\intercal\mathbf{X}_p)^{-1}\right\}. \tag{1}
$$

Looking at the smaller model's estimator, $\mathbf{A} = (\mathbf{X}_p^\intercal \mathbf{X}_p)^{-1}\mathbf{X}_p^\intercal \mathbf{X}_r$ so
\begin{align*}
\text{MSE}[\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}_p] &= V[\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}_p] + \mathbf{A}\boldsymbol{\beta}_r\boldsymbol{\beta}_r^\intercal \mathbf{A}^\intercal\\
&= \sigma^2(\mathbf{X}_p^\intercal \mathbf{X}_p)^{-1} + (\mathbf{X}_p^\intercal \mathbf{X}_p)^{-1}\mathbf{X}_p^\intercal \mathbf{X}_r \boldsymbol{\beta}_r\boldsymbol{\beta}_r^\intercal \mathbf{X}_r^\intercal \mathbf{X}_p (\mathbf{X}_p^\intercal \mathbf{X}_p)^{-1} \tag{2}\\
\end{align*}

Subtracting (2) from (1) yields
$$
(\mathbf{X}_p^\intercal \mathbf{X}_p)^{-1}\mathbf{X}_p^\intercal \mathbf{X}_r\left[ \sigma^2 (\mathbf{X}_r^\intercal\mathbf{X}_r - \mathbf{X}_r^\intercal \mathbf{X}_p (\mathbf{X}_p^\intercal\mathbf{X}_p)^{-1} \mathbf{X}_p^\intercal \mathbf{X}_r)^{-1}  - \boldsymbol{\beta}_r\boldsymbol{\beta}_r^\intercal \right]\mathbf{X}_r^\intercal \mathbf{X}_p (\mathbf{X}_p^\intercal \mathbf{X}_p)^{-1}
$$
which is positive semi-definite if this is as well:
$$
\sigma^2 (\mathbf{X}_r^\intercal\mathbf{X}_r - \mathbf{X}_r^\intercal \mathbf{X}_p (\mathbf{X}_p^\intercal\mathbf{X}_p)^{-1} \mathbf{X}_p^\intercal \mathbf{X}_r)^{-1}  - \boldsymbol{\beta}_r\boldsymbol{\beta}_r^\intercal.
$$
This is the same as the expression $V[\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}^*_r] - \boldsymbol{\beta}_r\boldsymbol{\beta}_r^\intercal$.

Comment: This answer seems to rely on the untenable assumption that the two error variances are the same.  That looks like a fundamental mistake to me: although it works mathematically, it has no application at all.

Comment: @whuber I don’t see why. One is just a location-shifted version of the other.